# How to executescript in sqlite3 from Python transactionally?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to execute a script in Sqlite3 from Python, and I want the entire script to be rolled back if it does not entirely succeed. Is this possible?

Here is what I've tried:

```
sql = open('my_file').read()
try:
        conn.executescript(sql)
        conn.commit()
    except sqlite3.OperationalError as oe:
        print('Failure to execute {0}: {1}'.format(f, oe))
        conn.rollback()
        exit(1)
```

But this doesn't work. When an error is thrown, the `commit` is not called, as it goes to the `except` block. Nevertheless, the parts of the script that worked persist to the database.

Comment: @Akilesh I'm not sure why I would want to. I don't want `commit` to be called in the case of error.

Comment: What is in the script? Data definition commands such as create table often have implicit commits.

Comment: @darthtater that is probably the issue.